# Query to find unique row and their count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table with rows like,

```
A
B
A
C
D
D
A
```

I want a table from that with unique row and count. So resultant table will be of two column like,

```
A 3
B 1
C 1
D 2
```

Having difficulty writing the query. Help?

Comment: I am not a sql coder. I can only use this and no idea about next step: SELECT DISTINCT Column1
  FROM table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, count(column1)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY column1
```